# How to disable automatic download of emails in Outlook for Office 365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

How do I disable the automatic download of emails in Outlook for Office 365 ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Outlook, Click on Send/Receive Groups, pull down, Define Send Receive Groups, and then for your account, Uncheck  "Include in Send/Receive"   Now you can send and receive manually. I do this.

Comment: Will 'Uncheck "Include in Send/Receive' affect the use of the Calendar in any way ?

Comment: No it will not affect Calendar

Comment: I have read somewhere that the ability to stop the automatic download of emails in Outlook may be affected by the Email protocol used to receive emails.

Comment: I don't think so. I have accounts here where I turn off automatic send/receive and all I have to do is manual send / receive. This is for POP and IMAP. Exchange is a bit different and you can also just lengthen the interval.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to disable automatic download is to activate "Offline mode" in Outlook.

```
Top menu > Send/Receive > Work Offline
```

You could also set up a "Send/receive group" and configure that to your preference.

This, however, is somewhat more advanced, so its difficult to give you a straight answer on how to set this up, as it depends what you want to achieve.

You can read more about what is possible with send/receive groups [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/why-use-send-receive-groups-86444f5e-b2e8-4379-810a-aa3de3186cf3).

Comment: Will use of 'Offline mode' affect use of the Calendar in any way ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your webmail and move the email you do not want to download to some other folder. keep in Inbox what you want to download.

Simple & effective way.

Answer (score 0):

Set outlook into online mode only.

Delete the OST from appdata for that profile on that user.

It should now only cache compressed & encrypted data for that profile.

If this does not answer please give clarity on what you are trying to achieve.

(This is without referencing and from memory.)